# Kafka connector for ArangoDB

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, arangodb, data-ingestion, data-connections

Can we use Apache Kafka to connect to ArangoDB? I can see the support for DirectMQ for ArangoDB but if I want to use Kafka to get data from various sources and store it on ArangoDB

Answer (score 0):

Can you? Yes.

Does a connector exist already? Maybe, maybe not.

That doesn't prevent you from writing your own, however, so therefore the answer is back to "yes", and "support" does not preclude your ability to use Kafka Connect, since it is an open source framework for anyone to develop on.